# Cannot start redis server on Centos 7 with systemctl

Tags: redis, centos7, systemctl

I have some trouble in starting Redis on CentOS7 with systemctl. What should I do to troubleshoot?

I can use the normal command to start the Redis. Like:

`# /etc/init.d/redis start`
or
`/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/config.conf`

And here is my redis.service file which I put into `/lib/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis persistent key-value database
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFILE=/var/run/redis_6379.pid
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/redis start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/redis stop
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I use command `systemctl start redis` to start redis server. I got nothing.

I try to use `systemctl status redis` to read the systemctl log, it shows me these messages:

```
● redis.service - Redis persistent key-value database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2018-08-31 15:45:37 CST; 2 days ago

Aug 31 15:45:37 redisserver001 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop redis_6379...
Aug 31 15:45:37 redisserver001 systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop redis_6379.
Aug 31 15:45:37 redisserver001 redis[24755]: /var/run/redis_6379.pid exists, process is already running or crashed
Sep 03 10:31:21 redisserver001 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'PIDFILE' in section 'Service'
Sep 03 10:33:13 redisserver001 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'PIDFILE' in section 'Service'
Sep 03 10:45:32 redisserver001 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service:7] Unknown lvalue 'PIDFILE' in section 'Service'
Sep 03 11:08:28 redisserver001 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service:7] Unknown lvalue 'PIDFILE' in section 'Service'
```

The following items is the key configration that I think could impact the redis running. But I donn't know where I've make mistakes. Please help. Thanks a lot.

```
pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid
daemonize yes
supervised systemd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an application specifies the "pidfile" property in the service file, then its the responsibility of the application to write the pid of the main process into that file, before the service initialization is complete. You need to make sure that your application is doing that. Systemd will read this value, and will prevent another forked process from being created if the user executes the "systemctl start ", and the pid file already exists. From the output you posted, it seems like systemd believes that the redis process is already running (because of the presence of the pid file, and doesnt create a new one). You can set the pid in the "ExecStartPost" clause of the service file. Something like:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'umask 022; pgrep YOURSERVICE > /var/run/YOURSERVICE.pid'
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I have tried to remove the `PIDFILE` setting within the `redis.service` file. But the `systemctl` still cannot start the service.

Comment: Did you also try to remove the file /var/run/pid_8579.pid ? An old artifact might be preventing your process from starting.

Comment: Yes. I also try to deleted the `/var/run/redis_6379.pid`. It still didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the output of "systemctl status redis" after you tried to start the server, after deleting the pid file ?

Comment: When I run `systemctl status redis` after deleting the pid file, the output didn't add any new messages for me. But I think I might find the real problem about this issue. When I kill the redis process, I could not use the `systemctl start redis` to bring redis up again, even if I remove the pid file. But I can use `systemctl restart redis` to bring it up. If I used `systemctl stop redis` to stop redis service as always, then the `systemctl start redis` will work fine. It's too weird.

Comment: Thats because the pid is not just stored on the disk (in the file), but also in memory of the **systemd** process. Its loaded into the memory when the redis process starts, and is cleared only when you execute `systemctl stop redis`. Thats why if you try to execute `systemctl start redis` after killing the process, systemd doesnt let you restart it. You can always enable autorestart in your service file, if you want that behavior, which will ensure that a new process is spawned each time the previous instantiation of the process gets killed.

Answer (score 0):

The option must be `PIDFile` (case sensetive). From the manpage `man systemd.service`

```
PIDFile=
  Takes a path referring to the PID file of the service. Usage of this option is recommended for
  services where Type= is set to forking. The path specified typically points to a file below /run/. If
  a relative path is specified it is hence prefixed with /run/. The service manager will read the PID
  of the main process of the service from this file after start-up of the service. The service manager
  will not write to the file configured here, although it will remove the file after the service has
  shut down if it still exists. The PID file does not need to be owned by a privileged user, but if it
  is owned by an unprivileged user additional safety restrictions are enforced: the file may not be a
  symlink to a file owned by a different user (neither directly nor indirectly), and the PID file must
  refer to a process already belonging to the service.
```